# Decode UTF-8 encoded Xcom value from SSHOperator

Tags: python, python-3.x, airflow

I have two Airflow tasks that I want to communicate. The SSHOperator returns the last line printed, in this case, "remote_IP". However, the SSHOperator's return value is encoded using UTF-8.

```python
Read_remote_IP = SSHOperator(
    task_id='Read_remote_IP',
    ssh_hook=hook,
    command="echo remote_IP ",
)

Read_SSH_Output = BashOperator(
    task_id='Read_SSH_Output',
    bash_command="echo {{ti.xcom_pull(task_ids='Read_remote_IP')}} ",
)
```

How can the SSHOperator `Read_remote_IP` return value non-encoded? Also, how can the BashOperator `Read_SSH_Output` decode the encoded value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My current solution is to introduce another Python operator to convert the string back, please feel free to provide other solutions.

```py
import base64
from airflow.operators.python import PythonOperator

def _decode_message(task_name, ti):
    message = ti.xcom_pull(task_ids=task_name)
    print(message)
    return base64.b64decode(message).decode()

Decode_SSH_Output = PythonOperator(
    task_id='Decode_SSH_Output',
    python_callable=_decode_message,
    op_args=['Read_remote_IP'],
)
```